# IIS7 webserver linq to sql error

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, webserver, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I configured a simple ASP.NET website on Windows Server 2008 R2 in IIS7 and it worked well, but now when I want it to use database for showing information, I get this error in Internet Explorer:

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataClassesDataContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:



`Line 10:    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`
`Line 11:    {`
`Line 12:    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();`
`Line 13:    var q = from i in db.Table1s`
`Line 14:            select i;`

Source File: c:\inetpub\oranges\sub\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 12
```

Then I tried that on windows 7 in IIS7 and **it works well!**

I used **LINQ-To-SQL** in Visual Studio 2010, and here is my code:

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
var q = from i in db.Table1s
        select i;

foreach (var i in q)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(i.data);
```

What's the problem?

How can I fix that??